# VB.NET - Combobox goes blank when a button is clicked, databind doesn't update

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Please forgive me, it has been some time since I've used VB.Net so this may be easy.

I have a simple login form with a text box, combobox and a button. The combobox is binded to a SQL database and displays the user names from Users table. The idea is that you select a name, type in a password, and you logon to a new form (This part works Great!). If you type a wrong password, the form pops up a message that says "invalid." For some reason at this stage, the combobox goes blank. The drop down now has empty spaces where names once were. Typing in a name with a password here results in object reference errors. I have tried everything to get the combo box to reset and searched the web but nothing works!!!

(I know this is not a secure login, this is just an easy example of binding data to a combo box and checking it against SQL table). Thanks for your help!

```
enter code here


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Logon.Click  

    Try  
    Dim STR_User As String = Users_nameComboBox.SelectedValue  
    Dim STR_Pwd As String = TB_Pwd.Text  
    STR_User = STR_User.Trim  

    'MessageBox.Show(STR_User & "|" & STR_Pwd)'Used to verify this stage works  
    Dim numRecords As Int16 = UsersTableAdapter.FillByLogin(Me.Login_testDataSet.users, STR_User, STR_Pwd)  
    'MessageBox.Show(numRecords) 'Used to verify this stage works  

     If (numRecords > 0) Then
     Dim DB_User As String = Me.Login_testDataSet.users(0).users_name.Trim
     Dim DB_Pwd As String = Me.Login_testDataSet.users(0).users_pwd.Trim
     'MessageBox.Show(DB_User & "|" & DB_Pwd)'Used to verify this stage works

     If DB_User.Equals(STR_User) And DB_Pwd.Equals(STR_Pwd) Then
     'User is authenticated for application
     'This section works (removed to cleanup code)

     Else
     MessageBox.Show("ERROR" & STR_User & "|" & STR_Pwd) 'Shows that this stage works
     'Need to figure out why combobox doesn't refill, using restart for now
     'Application.Restart()

     End If
     End If

     MessageBox.Show("ERROR" & STR_User & "|" & STR_Pwd) 'Shows that this stage works
     'Need to figure out why combobox doesn't refill, using restart for now
     'Application.Restart()


     Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     'Need to figure out why combobox doesn't refill, using restart for now
     'Application.Restart()

     End Try

     End Sub









     InitializeComponent

     'Users_nameComboBox

     Me.Users_nameComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
     Me.UsersBindingSource, "users_name", True))
     Me.Users_nameComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.UsersBindingSource, "users_name", True))
     Me.Users_nameComboBox.DataSource = Me.UsersBindingSource
     Me.Users_nameComboBox.DisplayMember = "users_name"
     Me.Users_nameComboBox.Name = "Users_nameComboBox"
     Me.Users_nameComboBox.ValueMember = "users_name"
```

Comment: Are you seeing the error message box twice?

Comment: Nope, double authentication. Error system and logon system work flawless. I narrowed down what causes the combobox to disappear, it is this:    Dim numRecords As Int16 =  UsersTableAdapter.FillByLogin(Me.Login_testDataSet.users, STR_User, STR_Pwd)

Comment: Any suggestions to revise this? FillByLogin is a simple SQL SELECT statement to check if TB_pwd = users_pwd in database